# Android Studio include "change color" options in app

Tags: android, mobile-development

I am programming an Android App and I am trying to include a "change color" option (in a settings-screen for example).
What I found out is that there are three colors in the "colors.xml" file (app->src->main->res->values):

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#ff4040</color>
```

The idea is, if possible, to change those colors by a press on a button, for example (a red button will change to red theme, a blue one to blue theme, and so on).
Is this anyhow possible? And if not, do you have a different idea to change colors?
I'm sorry if a question like this already exists. I did not find anything but I also had no idea what to look for.

Thank you in advance :)

Edit:

currently, I am trying it that way:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_dark:
        setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Dark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_light:
        setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Light", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_settings_save:
        Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        break;
    }
}
```

Meaning, I want to change it by calling the onCreate in the MainActivity when pressing the save button I am trying to reset the "setContentView".

Where do I have to set all the Themes? In the Manifest? Because when I set it in the OnCreate I will overwrite my changes done in the "settings"-Activity, or am I wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use style.

Suppose you have two style in style.xml file.

```
<style name="AppThemeRed" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Now on button press you have to set style from java. For ex:

```
 setTheme(R.style.AppThemeRed);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

To use style colorPrimary just give **?colorPrimary** in layout in the place of **@color/colorPrimary**

You can look at this sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ShohanAhmed/AndroidAppMultipleTheme).

Thanks

Comment: added information to the originial post, it is easier to read than here.

Comment: I just update my answer. And I also create a new repository for you. Hope your problem will solve now.

Comment: Hello again.. I did it now (by using shared preferences, because I have multiple activities) but have a new problem.. Again it has something to do with colors but I would say it is a different problem. Should I open a new question or add it here?

Comment: If your current problem solve then mark a answer as right first... And then ask a new question & give question link in here by comment @EXQulsllt

Comment: Thanks to you for your help! Altough I did it a bit different, your solution brought me on the right way :)

Here is the link to my new problem this whole color-thing has caused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809244/android-development-change-color-of-specific-textview-in-specific-themes

Answer (score 0):

Those three colors are all  used in the application activity by default, the Accent color is the most noticeable because it is the color of the floating button by default. If what you want to do is to change the color/theme of the app based on user preference research on 'Shared Preferences and how to have different colors that make up a theme based on user's choice'. :)